# How is the body of a androginus or tumtum hung?

Tags: women, men-male, beit-din-court, capital-punishment, androgynous

If an androginus (person possessing both sex organs) or tumtum (person of unspecific gender) is punished by beis din for a capital case and then hung, how is the body displayed? Like a man (naked but genitals covered in front and facing the people) or a woman (naked but genitals covered and front and back and not facing the people) or entirely differently?

Comment: It looks like this question would be on a much stronger footing if @please consults the sources for the standard treatments of men and women that he/she is alluding to and [edit]s the post to cite them and reflect them more precisely.

Comment: According to Sota perek 3, mishna 8, the woman does not punished naked: "האיש נסקל ערם, ואין האשה נסקלת ערמה."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Halacha is clear that both androginus and tumtum are limited by rules for both men and women. (E.g. Just like a man cannot marry a man, so too, androginus and tumtum cannot marry a man. Just like a woman cannot marry a woman, so too, androginus and tumtum cannot marry a woman.) Therefore, in this case, both would treated like a woman; a woman's back may not be uncovered, and she may not be hung.

Comment: Since it is not clearly forbidden for a woman to marry a woman an androginus can marry a woman

Comment: @Adam what is the Tanach or Talmudic word for a hermaphrodite, a person who possesses the sexual organs of both male and female?

Comment: @ninamag Tanach doesn't mention any, but the Talmud uses "androginus", clearly borrowed from Greek.